# Icons list bug on Navigation bar - Developer Jobs page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs, top-bar

> **Icons list doesn't fill 100% height of the navbar.**

I just realized there's a "bug" on the **icons list** in the Navigation bar, situated on the right side next to the user's points and badges at the [Developer Jobs' page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) due to the following CSS style being implemented:

```
li {
    padding-bottom: 7px; /* this padding */
    line-height: 1.375;
}
```

From the file: `jobs.min.css`.

### Here's two print screens:

Developer Jobs page:

[image]

Normal page is ok:

[image]

Comment: hmm yeah there is a slight padding difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. Fix is now waiting in repo and should be up in couple hours.